# pyparsing validation on single/double quotes on strings

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a formula format which is something like this:

```
lhs = pp.Word(pp.alphas + pp.alphas8bit + pp.alphanums + "." + "_")
rhs = (
    pp.Optional(pp.oneOf("' \""))
    + pp.Word(pp.alphas + pp.alphas8bit + pp.alphanums + "." + "_" + "-" + ":")
    + pp.Optional(pp.oneOf("' \""))
)
expression = lhs + pp.oneOf("> < = >= <=") + rhs
```

So, it works fine:

```
>>> print(expression.parseString("name = 'user1'"))
>>> ['name', '=', "'", 'user1', "'"]
>>> print(expression.parseString('user.id >= 10'))
>>> ['user.id', '>=', '10']
```

But, how to validate when the `rhs` starts with `"` it must be ended with `"` (double quote) as well and the same for `'` (single quote). Also, when input starts with none of them (like Integer) it must end with none of them as well. But now it never validates them:

```
>>> print(expression.parseString("name = \"user1'"))  # invalid!
>>> ['name', '=', '"', 'user1', "'"]
>>> print(expression.parseString('user.id >= 10"'))  # invalid!
>>> ['user.id', '>=', '10', '"']
```

So, how to have a validation like this?

Comment: Your lhs expression works on valid inputs, but would also match "a...b", ".3..9a." See https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/wiki/Common-Pitfalls-When-Writing-Parsers for more detailed description.

Comment: You can replace `pp.alphas + pp.alphas8bit + pp.alphanums` with `pp.pyparsing_unicode.Latin1.alphanums`, which includes all the 8-bit alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
lhs = pp.Word(pp.alphas + pp.alphas8bit + pp.alphanums + "." + "_")
rhs_str = pp.Word(pp.alphas + pp.alphas8bit + pp.alphanums + "." + "_" + "-" + ":")
rhs_num = pp.Word(pp.nums)
rhs = (
    (pp.Suppress('"') + rhs_str + pp.Suppress('"'))
    ^ (pp.Suppress("'") + rhs_str + pp.Suppress("'"))
    ^ (rhs_num)
)
expression = lhs + pp.oneOf("> < = >= <=") + rhs
```

Comment: Using '^' will work, but it always evaluates *all* alternatives and chooses the longest match - useful when there is some potential overlap in the alternative expressions. In this case, there is no overlap, so '|' operator will be more efficient. You can also try replacing your own quoted string expressions with the pyparsing builtins `quotedString`, or `QuotedString` .